# Is it possible to figure out whether a 'user' is 'roaming'

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question whether it is possible to write a query to figure out whether `user` is/were `roaming`.

I have a `type users` that has `home geo location`:

`curl -XGET "xxxxxxxxx/users/_mapping?pretty=true"
{
  "xxxxx" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "users" : {
        "properties" : {
          ....
          "location" : {
            "type" : "geo_point"
          },
          ....
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

I also have a `type clicks` that has a `geo location` of where click happened and when it happened (`eventTimestamp`). `clicks` is also set as being a child of `users`:

`curl -XGET "xxxxxx/clicks/_mapping?pretty=true"
{
  "xxxxx" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "clicks" : {
        "_parent" : {
          "type" : "users"
        },
        "_routing" : {
          "required" : true
        },
        "properties" : {
          ....
          "eventTimestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "location" : {
            "type" : "geo_point"
          },
          ....
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
 
What i am interested in is getting all the users who were outside of their `home` locations in the past `x days` for example.
When i say outside of their `home` locations, lets say, outside 250 mil radius from their `home geo`.

any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to do two queries to accomplish this. First, run a simple query for all users. Then iterate over the results and for each user do a query for clicks that uses a filter that checks if the `eventTimestamp` is greater than the date x days ago and a `geo_distance_range` filter to test for click locations greater than 250mi from the current user. This second query might look something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
     "filtered": {
       "query": {"match_all": {}},
       "filter": {
         "and": [
           {
             "range": {
               "eventTimestamp": {"gte": "2015-11-01"}
             }
           },
           {
             "geo_distance_filter": {
               "gte": "250mi",
               "location": {
                 "lat": <latitude from current user>,
                 "lon": <longitude from current user>
               }
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     }
  }
}
```

The reason you have to use two queries is that Elasticsearch has no way to compare two fields without using a script. Of course, you could try using a script... but I'm not sure if there's a way to calculate geo distance with scripts.

Another option would be to include the `eventTimestamp` filtering in the first query (using a `has_child` query to check the clicks made after the given date). Then again iterate over those results and filter this time only by the `geo_distance_range`.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: thank you very much for your response. You can use script that calculates distance, this way `doc['location'].distance(lat,lon)` the problem is that you can reference only to the matches of the query and there is no way (at least i could not find) to reference to lat/lon of other records within other `type`